Add text to multiple selected lines at once
i have this
{
"name": "10",
"ref": "10"
},
{
"name": "100"
"ref": "100"
}

who would i add to the "ref" and / to make it look like this on hundreds of lines on at once
{
"name": "10",
"ref": "10/",
"item_count": 1
},
{
"name": "100",
"ref": "100/",
"item_count": 1
}


You can either use "Find and Replace" with regular expressions:
Find ("ref": "\d+)"  and replace with $1/",\n  "item_count": 1
Or you can use the multiple select feature of VSCode. Select the first instance of "ref": and hit Ctrl+D until all instances are selected. Then do your edits ...

that worked tyvm
